# Proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ with finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a non-trivial subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$, such that $|\mathbb{Q^{+}} : H|$ is finite? Of course, $|H| = \aleph_0$, but I could not prove that such $H$ does not exist (I think it does not exist at least).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These questions are only very weakly related (being about groups). Could you please ask them separately?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft There are some homework questions in MathStack that follows this format, so I don't know if it's really necessary to ask them separately (actually I don't want to ask 5 questions in a day).

Comment: The idea of asking them separately is that then a proper answer will not need to deal with more than one of them.

Comment: @Excelsior How are you interpreting $\mathbb Q^+$? It seems like $\mathbb Z^+$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^+$. But if the author means $(\mathbb Q,+)$ then $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is a subgroup...

Comment: @user40276 This is the wrong approach in general, unless the problems are a natural sequence. How do you pick a "right answer" if each person picks only one problem to answer? If you don't want to ask five questions in one day, you just have. You've just counted it wrong.

Comment: 1) $y = x^5 y x^{-5} = x^4 y^2 x^{-4} = \dots = y^{32}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ is a group under multiplication.

Comment: That was my assumption, @user40276, but then the comment above is wrong because $\mathbb Z^+$ is not a subgroup if that group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So, I should edit the question or delete it?

Comment: I would edit the question to just contain one of those questions. Then ask the remaining as separate questions

Comment: **How is this too localized**?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: It was before the edit, when this question contained five different questions, and the only relation between them was group theory. I don't think questions like that belong here. Now the question is okay, but it seems that removing close votes is not possible

Comment: @m.k. Oh, OK. Good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the group operation on $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is multiplication (and that the set is the set of positive rational numbers).  Then consider the subgroup $H$ consisting of those positive rational numbers whose numerators and denominators, when written in lowest terms, have prime factorizations that contain only even powers of 2.  Then $|\mathbb{Q}^+ : H| = 2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "when written in lowest terms"? The denominator and numerator are coprime?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use prime factorization to show that the multiplicative group ${\bf Q}^+$ is in fact isomorphic to ${\bf Z}^{\oplus\aleph_0}$, a direct sum of countably infinitely many copies of integers (additive).

From that it should be easy to find subgroups of arbitrary countable index.

As a side note, ${\bf Q}$ with addition is *much* more complicated, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Of course, $\mathbf{Q}$ is [divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), so it can't be a sum or product of cyclic groups.

Comment: I think that it's not exactly isomorphic to the coproduct of the additive integers (or I'm missing something), but the idea of put each prime in a coordinate helped me in understand better the intuition in the existence of such subgroup $H$.

Comment: @user40276: It is. Fix an enumeration $p_n$ of prime numbers. Then for any finitely supported $f\colon {\bf N}\to {\bf Z}$ put $\varphi(f)=\prod p_n^{f(n)}$ -- $\varphi$ will be an isomorphism.